# How to wrap 32-bit (4 bytes) emojis in arbitrary string using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, utf8mb4

I'm using this PHP function to wrap emojis in arbitrary HTML tags, which allows me to style them on web pages, since CSS3 does not (yet?) directly support styling of multi-byte characters, at least I haven't found any CSS selector for that purpose:

```
function wrap_emojis($s, $str_before, $str_after) {
    $default_encoding = mb_regex_encoding();
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    $s = mb_ereg_replace('([^\x{0000}-\x{FFFF}])', $str_before . '\\1' . $str_after, $s);
    mb_regex_encoding($default_encoding);
    return $s;
}
```

The issue is that it works for lower range emojis such as  (01F60E) but it does not work for higher range emojis such as ☀️ (2600FE0F)

Any ideas how to fix the PHP function so that it works with 4 bytes range as well?

e.g. if I call wrap_emojis("zzz☀️zzz", "A", "B"); Expected result: "zzzA☀️Bzzz". Actual result: "zzz☀️zzz". But it works with lower range emojis as noted in the question, e.g. wrap_emojis("zzzzzz", "A", "B") returns: "zzzABzzz"

Comment: Can you give an example call to `wrap_emojis` with the parameters and what to expect as result?

Comment: wrap_emojis("XYZ☀️XYZ", "A", "B"); Expected result: "XYZA☀️BXYZ".  Actual result: "XYZ☀️XYZ".  But it works with lower range emojis as noted in the question.

Comment: This seems to work: https://3v4l.org/gR5o1 Note the little eye icon in right top corner of the output to see the processed HTML.

Comment: OK but you stripped all the code that detects the emojis? It needs to detect automatically, like for 500 of them in a huge string, it needs to wrap only the emojis.  I've edited my comment above to make more clear.

Comment: Ah, OK, I get it. Yes, a proper usage example would have been nice.

Comment: I've added it to the question.  Thanks for replying, I appreciate it.

Comment: I came across [this one](https://regex101.com/r/hQuJGU/1) [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-test-regex-pattern/blob/main/dist/latest/cpp-re2.txt) ([php usage example with `preg_replace`](https://3v4l.org/aEcNk#v8.2.9)). Have not modified or checked anyhting on the regex. It looks huge, not sure if this should be used in production. :)

Comment: FWIW that's not a "high range" anything, that's a 2-codepoint sequence. It's a u2600 which is ☀ and a uFE0F "variation selector" to produce the glyph that's actually rendered.

Comment: @bobblebubble Those are baked in an array of emojis.  It's indeed pretty inefficient compared to a simple range RegEx and it needs to be updated every time we find out that an emoji that has been left out by that huge array.

Comment: @Sammitch So then, the question could be further simplified to: How to write the mb_ereg_replace() function call to include this "variation selectors" range of bytes?

Comment: As much as you might dislike @bobblebubble's linked regex, that's the reality of emoji. It is a vast mishmash of ranges scattered across unicode, a portal to "Combining Mark Hell", and only gets more complicated every time the Unicode Consortium updates the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it wasn't that hard, I just had to write the RegEx matching 2 groups of 2 bytes (mb4 with "variation selector") OR (when none is found) then any character not in lower 2 bytes range.  Pretty sure it will cause issues in foreign languages, but in English, it works great!

```
$s = mb_ereg_replace('([\x{0100}-\x{FFFF}][\x{0000}-\x{FFFF}]|[^\x{0000}-\x{FFFF}])', $str_before . '\\1' . $str_after, $s);
```

Hope it enlightens other people on here.  Cheers